# Stream data disappears from StreamBuilder when we Drag a widget using LongPressDraggable

Tags: android, flutter

*I had created a widget using LongPressDraggable. When I perform the drag operation then stream data (StreamBuilder) disappear from the screen. Attaching the code for your reference.*

**main.dart**

In the main.dart, I had defined a Stack widget. Inside Stack widget, I had defined a BaseWidget. Base widget takes TextStream widget as parameter

```html
import 'package:example/base_widget.dart';
import 'package:example/text_stream.dart';
import 'package:example/widget_view_model.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
      MultiProvider(providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<WidgetViewModel>(
          create: (context) => WidgetViewModel(),
        ),
      ], child: const MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    WidgetViewModel widgetViewModel = context.read<WidgetViewModel>();

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            BaseWidget(widgetItem: TextStream(value: widgetViewModel.textStream))
            ]
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**text_stream.dart**

In the text_stream.dart, I had defined a StreamBuilder which takes Stream of string as its  parameter. StreamBuilder returns TextWidget when the snapshot data is found

```html
import 'package:example/text_widget.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TextStream extends StatefulWidget {
  final Stream<String> value;

  const TextStream({Key? key, required this.value}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TextStream> createState() => _TextStreamState();
}

class _TextStreamState extends State<TextStream> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<String>(
        stream: widget.value,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if(snapshot.hasData){
            return TextWidget(text: snapshot.data!);
          }
          else {
            return const TextWidget(text: "Unknown");
          }
        });
  }
}
```

**base_widget.dart**

base_widget.dart contains implementation of LongPressDraggable and Positioned widget.

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BaseWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget widgetItem;

  const BaseWidget({Key? key, required this.widgetItem}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<BaseWidget> createState() => _BaseWidgetState();
}

class _BaseWidgetState extends State<BaseWidget> {
  double _x = 0.0;
  double _y = 0.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Positioned(
      left: _x,
      top: _y,
      child: LongPressDraggable(
          feedback: widget.widgetItem,
          childWhenDragging: const SizedBox(),
          onDragEnd: (details) {
            setState(() {
              _x = details.offset.dx;
              _y = details.offset.dy;
            });
          },
          child: widget.widgetItem,

          ),
    );
  }
}
```

**widget_view_model.dart**

It contains implementation of EventChannel (client side) which takes value from android host.

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class WidgetViewModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  static const textEvent = EventChannel("com.example.example");

  Stream<String> textStream = textEvent.receiveBroadcastStream().distinct().map((event) {
    return event as String;
  });
}
```

**text_widget.dart**

It contains an implementation of Container and Text widget. TextStream class takes String value as its input parameter.

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class TextWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final String text;
  const TextWidget({Key? key, required this.text}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TextWidget> createState() => _TextWidgetState();
}

class _TextWidgetState extends State<TextWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.amber,
      height: 100.0,
      width: 100.0,
      child: Text(
        widget.text,
        style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**MainActivity.kt**

It implement EventChannel stream handler and event sink to pass the value on the Flutter side.

```html
package com.example.example

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugin.common.EventChannel

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    private val textEvent = "com.example.example"

    private var textEventSink: EventChannel.EventSink? = null

    override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
        EventChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger,textEvent).setStreamHandler(
            object: EventChannel.StreamHandler {
                override fun onListen(arguments: Any?, events: EventChannel.EventSink?) {
                    textEventSink = events
                    textEventSink?.success("Harsh")
                }

                override fun onCancel(arguments: Any?) {
                    textEventSink?.success("Harsh")
                    textEventSink = null
                }

            }
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The stream data (StreamBuilder) is not disappear, is just being rebuild and waiting next value from stream, but your textStream did not emit any value after first build,Your code is fine if the stream keeps emitting values.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import 'example/base_widget.dart';
import 'example/text_stream.dart';
import 'example/widget_view_model.dart';

void main() {
  /// stack overflow:
  /// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76571124/stream-data-disappears-from-streambuilder-when-we-drag-a-widget-using-longpressd
  ///
  runApp(MultiProvider(providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider<WidgetViewModel>(
      create: (context) => WidgetViewModel(),
    ),
  ], child: const MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    WidgetViewModel widgetViewModel = context.read<WidgetViewModel>();
    
    /// [edit]
    Stream<String> countStream(int to) async* {
      for (int i = 1; i <= to; i++) {
        await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3));
        yield 'Seconds-> $i';
      }
    }
   /// [end edit]
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
          BaseWidget(widgetItem: TextStream(value: widgetViewModel.textStream)),
          BaseWidget(
              widgetItem:
                  TextStream(value: countStream(30).asBroadcastStream())) // listen custom stream
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
```

//
below is some code I modify for store the stream value.

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import 'example/base_widget.dart';
import 'example/text_stream.dart';
import 'example/widget_view_model.dart';

void main() {
  /// solve the stack overflow:
  /// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76571124/stream-data-disappears-from-streambuilder-when-we-drag-a-widget-using-longpressd
  ///
  runApp(MultiProvider(providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider<WidgetViewModel>(
      create: (context) => WidgetViewModel(),
    ),
  ], child: const MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    WidgetViewModel widgetViewModel = context.read<WidgetViewModel>();

    Stream<String> countStream(int to) async* {
      for (int i = 1; i <= to; i++) {
        await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3));
        yield 'Seconds-> $i';
      }
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
          // BaseWidget(widgetItem: TextStream(value: widgetViewModel.textStream)),
          BaseWidget(
              valueMessenger:
                  ValueMessenger(value: widgetViewModel.textStream)),
          BaseWidget(
            valueMessenger: ValueMessenger(value: countStream(300)),
          ),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

text_widget.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

/// no any state in this widget.
class TextWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  const TextWidget({Key? key, required this.text}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.amber,
      height: 100.0,
      width: 100.0,
      child: Text(
        text,
        style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

text_stream.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'text_widget.dart';

class ValueMessenger extends ChangeNotifier {
  Widget? _currentWidget;
  final Stream<String> value;
  ValueMessenger({required this.value}) {
    value.listen((event) {
      setCurrentWidget(TextWidget(text: event));
    });
  }

  void setCurrentWidget(Widget widget) {
    _currentWidget = widget;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Widget getCurrentWidget() {
    return _currentWidget ?? const TextWidget(text: 'Unknown');
  }
}
```

base_widget.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:stack_overflow_stream/example/text_stream.dart';

class BaseWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final ValueMessenger valueMessenger;

  const BaseWidget({Key? key, required this.valueMessenger}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<BaseWidget> createState() => _BaseWidgetState();
}

class _BaseWidgetState extends State<BaseWidget> {
  double _x = 0.0;
  double _y = 0.0;
  late Widget widgetItem;
  @override
  void initState() {

    widgetItem = widget.valueMessenger.getCurrentWidget();
    widget.valueMessenger.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        widgetItem = widget.valueMessenger.getCurrentWidget();
      });
    });

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Positioned(
      left: _x,
      top: _y,
      child: LongPressDraggable(
        feedback: widgetItem,
        childWhenDragging: const SizedBox(),
        onDragEnd: (details) {
          setState(() {
            _x = details.offset.dx;
            _y = details.offset.dy;
          });
        },
        child: widgetItem,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

text_widget.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

/// no any state in this widget.
class TextWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  const TextWidget({Key? key, required this.text}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.amber,
      height: 100.0,
      width: 100.0,
      child: Text(
        text,
        style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

NOTE!! this method still fails to update the "feedback" parameter during onDrag.

Comment: I want the values coming from widgetViewModel.textStream to remain on the screen while drag / drop is performed. How can we achieve this?